# Make names anonymous in reports SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am not an SQL expert and have the following challenge ahead of me. I have a table which contains a note field next to the name of the person concerned. The note field is a free text, which can contain the name of a person. I would like to make it anonymous.

An example for better understanding: Table "Reports"

```
ID | PersonID | Name  | Notefield
 1 | 978      | Max   | Max isn't feeling so good today.
 2 | 234      | Julia | Julia's blood sugar has improved.
 3 | ...
```

The result should look like this:

```
ID | PersonID | Name  | Notefield
 1 | 978      | Max   | M. isn't feeling so good today.
 2 | 234      | Julia | J. blood sugar has improved.
 3 | ...
```

So I want to change the note field depending on the name. Can anyone here help?

Comment: Regular expression should do the magic.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `replace`

```
REPLACE(Notefield, Name, LEFT(Name,1) + '.'  )
```

Comment: This solution works if your data is perfect. I would be careful though. Since your notefield column is free text the name could be there but misspelled. In that scenario the name passes through to your output.

Answer (score 0):

This can be dangerous as it will replace parts of normal words. E.g. "Maximize". You must search for REPLACE(Notefield, Name + '[space]', LEFT(Name,1) + '.'  )